# G-wan xbuf_xcat(), is it a memory leak?

Tags: c, g-wan

I meet a problem about reply request on gwan, while I call function       `xbuf_xcat(get_reply(argv), replycontent)`, the RSS value keep rising up. If I comment this function or change to `xbuf_xcat(get_reply(argv), "value=1")`, this strange phenomenon won't happen...

> root     20365  0.5  0.8 403848  **6468** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root     20365  0.5  0.8 403848  **6488** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root     20365  0.5  0.8 403848  **6492** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root     20365  0.5  0.8 403848  **6496** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root     20365  0.5  0.8 403848  **6500** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root     20365  0.5  0.8 403848  **6504** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root     20365  0.6  0.8 403848  **6504** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root     20365  0.6  0.8 403848  **6528** pts/0    Sl+  15:07   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan

(If I run it overnight, consume nearly 1GB memory...)
Any idea ??

The code I modify:

```
xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
xbuf_t f;
xbuf_init(&f);
xbuf_cat(&f,replycontent);
xbuf_ncat(reply, f.ptr, f.len);
xbuf_free(&f);
```

Below are the code content: (I simply it not to use the function I write, but RSS still rising for every 7-10 sec)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("G-wan start Serving...\n");
    char replycontent[1024];

    //set replycontent value
    strcpy(replycontent, "[");
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<2; i++){
        strcpy(replycontent, "TEST ONLY");
        strcat(replycontent, ",");
    }
    replycontent[strlen(contents)-1] = ']';

    xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
    xbuf_xcat(reply, replycontent);
    return 200;
}
```

RSS result:

> root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5748** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5748** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5748** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5748** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  0.7 555392  **5756** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  1.0 555392  **7676** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  1.0 555392  **7676** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  1.0 555392  **7676** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  1.0 555392  **7680** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  1.0 555392  **7680** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan
>   root      8170  0.3  1.0 555392  **7684** pts/0    Sl+  10:29   0:00  |       _ /opt/gwan/gwan

If I change `xbuf_xcat(reply, replycontent);` to `printf("reply:%s\n",replycontent);` , the RSS is stable, but suddenly rise still occur.

Comment: Do you ever call `xbuf_free()` on the buffer?

Comment: No, never, is it necessary to do this?

Comment: do replycontent needed to be free?

Comment: What's the complete code/testcase? Your leak could be on a differnt part of the code, and by commenting out the xbuf line, the compiler could optimize away other parts of the code as well.

Comment: I have upload my code, please take a look, thanks!!

Comment: This code is using a buffer allocated on the stack so it does not change the memory usage. Besides, you should directly write into the 'reply' xbuffer rather than into a temporary buffer and then copied - and to copy, you should rather use xbuf_cat() or xbuf_ncat(), not xbuf_xcat().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With `xbuf_xcat(get_reply(argv), replycontent)`, RSS value grows 
>   With `xbuf_xcat(get_reply(argv), "value=1")`, memory usage is stable

As shown by the working `xbuf_xcat(reply, "value=1")`, G-WAN automatically recycles the memory allocated for the `reply` xbuffer, so this is not the problem.

Your problem rather comes from how you are generating the `replycontent`.

And this portion of the code is missing in your question. If you are asking for assistance, it might help to show what you are doing.

---

UPDATE (following the source code disclosure in the question)

Your code is using a small buffer allocated on the stack so it does not change the memory usage of G-WAN.

Besides, you should directly write into the 'reply' xbuffer rather than into a temporary buffer which is then copied into the 'reply' xbuffer - and to make such a copy, you should rather use xbuf_cat() or xbuf_ncat(), but not xbuf_xcat().

Given this (undamaging but pointless) code, the "sudden raise" of memory you have seen could come from problems in other scripts (handlers? maintenance script?, OS/VM configuration?), or from the tests you make if you are using very high concurrencies.

Maybe you could try writing G-WAN servlets in another programming language than C (G-WAN supports 15 different programming languages, including Java, C#, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.), this would help you to avoid most memory allocation pitfalls.

Comment: Beside, the memory usage will rise up suddenly even I don't send any request to the server, say, the RSS rise from 5900 to 7800, is it normal ?

Comment: Without client activity G-WAN won't need to allocate more memory, unless you have a virtual machine (Xen, VMWare, etc.), a G-WAN maintenance script or a G-WAN handler going havok.

Comment: Actually, I test G-wan under Virtualbox, and when I change to other machine, this strange problem disappear!!! Thank you very much!!! However, the sudden rise of memory still occur ( I don't set any handler, maintenance script etc)

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a classical memory leak.

Note that the (in my opinion, weirdly-named) formatting function `xbuf_xcat()` function will dynamically allocate memory to  hold the resulting text.

If you don't call `xbuf_free()` on the `xbuf_t` passed to `xbuf_xcat()`, the memory is leaked.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, after I try to use xbuf_free, still got the same result, RSS still rising up on every request...

Comment: If you call `xbuf_free()` on the `reply` xbuffer then G-WAN won't be able to serve the (freed) reply you have built. NEVER free the `reply` buffer. The problem rather comes from how the 'replycontent' is generated (something that the question does not disclose).